# AMQP transactions with Kombu and Rabbitmq

Tags: transactions, rabbitmq, amqp, kombu, py-amqplib

I cant seem to find any documentation on using [AMQP transactions](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#class.tx) through the [Kombu](https://github.com/ask/kombu) api.
[This page](http://packages.python.org/kombu/reference/kombu.transport.virtual.html?highlight=transaction) talks about appending a message to the transactional state but it does not seem related.

I know the pika backend supports them and I am quite sure the amqplib backend (which Im currently using) does too but I dont yet see how this is exposed in Kombu.

**Edit**: to clarify, Im looking for channel.commit(), channel.select(), ... type methods

Comment: I had a brief look at the Kombu docs and cannot find anything related to AMQP transaction control. It may well be that it's just not supported by that wrapper library's API yet. I'll let others more familiar with it post an answer which is definitive.

Comment: @Brian Kelly: thanks, I agree.  I have opened an issue: https://github.com/ask/kombu/issues/46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turns out](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/46) that transactions were specifically not exposed as they are not as useful as I had thought at first.  Specifically the tx set of commands are only valid across a single queue and RabbitMQ will very likely remove the support for the tx class altogether.

A full discussion can be found on the [rabbitmq mailing list](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-June/013448.html)